# How to use #IF DEBUG in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net

Is it possible to assign a value to a class variable from inside a `#IF DEBUG` conditional?

I want to conditionally execute some code from inside my main form load if I am running in `DEBUG` mode. I thought I could do something like:

```
Public Class Form1
    public DEB as Integer

    #if DEBUG then
        DEB = 1
    #else
        DEB = 0
    #end if

    Private Sub Form1_Load(....)
        if DEB=1 Then
            <do something>
        else
            <do something else>
        end if
    ....
```

However, it seems like you can't assign a value to a variable. I'm obviously not understanding the scoping correctly. I can't seem to put the `#if DEBUG` inside the Load sub routine. How do I do this?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Why not just test the compilation constant directly? You are not gaining anything by testing an actual variable.

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(....)

#if DEBUG then
    <do something>
#else 
    <do something else>
#end if

End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Good point...but it seems like DEBUG is not set when I run it.  I know I am running in DEBUG mode though.

Comment: Figured it out...the Solution was defined as "Release" build even though the project was defined to build in DEBUG.

Comment: Another thing to check is Project properties -> Compile -> Advanced Compile Options -> "Define DEBUG Constant" which has to be unchecked in the Release configuration.

Answer (score 2):

In VB.NETFramework v4.5

> Debugger.IsAttached

```
Public DEB As Integer
If Debugger.IsAttached Then
    DEB = 1
Else
    DEB = 0
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your problem here. I do this and it works fine. It's a bit annoying that the compilation constant isn't available directly to running code but it makes sense when you think about it.

In response to Christian, I think the case against just enclosing your code in the compiler directives is that with a code variable you can write cleaner, more descriptive code with potentially less duplication and therefore simpler maintenance.

For example, here's my standard library code:

```
Public Module Common

    #if DEBUG then
        Public In_Debug As Boolean = True
    #else
        Public In_Debug As Boolean = False
    #end if
End Module

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(....)

        If In_Debug Then SplashScreen.Hide()
        ...
```

Placing the `In-Debug` code variable in a public module effectively makes it a *Global* which you can treat as a constant throughout your project.

(Example explanation: I don't show the splash screen in debug because it may hide dialogs, etc which can stop you progressing.)

Obviously, you can do the same thing with the TRACE constant or any custom compiler constant you choose to declare.

And, yes, as GregH mentioned, you need to make sure that you actually have a DEBUG constant declared in your project's *Debug* configuration (whether or not it's actually called "Debug"). You don't need it declared in *Release*; it's absence is interpreted as "False".