# terminate application using full path

Tags: vb.net

I want to terminate an application using the full file path via vb.net,so i am using this code snippet

```
Public Sub forceCopy()
        Try
            'Dim strDatabasePath As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.CombinePath(Application.UserAppDataPath, "LIC.mdf")
            'Dim strdbLogPath As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.CombinePath(Application.UserAppDataPath, "LIC_log.ldf")
            Dim strDatabasePath As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.CombinePath(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath, "LIC.mdf")
            Dim strdbLogPath As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.CombinePath(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath, "LIC_log.ldf")
            Dim path As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.CombinePath(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath, "LIC.mdf")
            Dim matchingProcesses = New List(Of Process)

            For Each process As Process In process.GetProcesses()
                For Each m As ProcessModule In process.Modules
                    If String.Compare(m.FileName, path, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) = 0 Then
                        matchingProcesses.Add(process)
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
            Next

            For Each p As Process In matchingProcesses
                p.Kill()
            Next
            My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(strDatabasePath, "c:\backup\LIC.mdf", True)

            My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(strdbLogPath, "c:\backup\LIC_log.ldf", True)

            MessageBox.Show("Backup taken successfully")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try


    End Sub
```

I get an exception **"Access Is Denied"** .Any idea why?
EDIT: I get the error at this line : `For Each m As ProcessModule In process.Modules`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to wrap the `If String.Compare(m.FileName, ...)` block with Try/Catch.  There are several fake and privileged processes whose FileName property you cannot access.

Killing SQL Server like this is otherwise a Really Bad Idea.  Ask nicely with the ServiceController class.  You will need [UAC elevation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-to-force-c-sharp-app-to-run-as-administrator-on-windows-7/2818776#2818776) to do so.

Comment: i just need to copy this files..any way is good for me...i do not want to back/restore the DB..just a simple copy..but because of the "File is being used by another process" error...i cannot copy...any solutions for this??

Comment: Asked and answered.  Do *not* kill processes unless you like making backups of corrupt files.  The file is locked for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

Only elevated processes can enumerate modules loaded by processes that you do not own.

Comment: So is there a way using which i can know which process is using the .mdf file and kill the process??

Comment: You would probably be better off using a volume shadow copy. This would at least have the advantage of being in a consistent state.

Comment: what is volume shadow copy??point me some good links...thanks.

Comment: This might get you started: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/makeshadowcopy.aspx