# How do hide the buttons when I debug a script in VB.net (visual studio code)

Tags: vb.net, forms, visual-studio, button

I am new to visual studio and visual basic. I am finding problem when I try to hide or make a button invisible when I turn on the debugging mode. I am aware of the Hide() and Visible functions, but, they hide or make the corresponding buttons invisible only when they are clicked, but I want to make them hide from my form during the start of the debug session.

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613249/how-to-use-if-debug-in-vb-net

Comment: Set the `Visible` properties in the Properties window of the designer, just like you would for any other properties.

Comment: Thank you, I did not explore much of the options available in the properties window.
Also thank you @J.Salas for your response

Comment: Or set Visible properties in [Form.Load](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.load?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) event

Comment: Is there anyway to write a routine that makes the buttons hide for a while? If I change the properties of the button, then the property remains unchanged. But, let us say that I need a button to be visible for one particular instance and want to make it visible for another instance, will there be any other alternative way to do it?
In detail, My work has two forms, one form as the general layout and the other as the main form. The general layout consist of different buttons, in which I have to display different interfaces in the main form correspondingly. 
Is there any way of solving this?

Comment: @GowthamKumaraguru To me, it sounds like you should create a separate form for each Button, instead of trying to make one mega-Form that creates different appearances depending on which Button is clicked. This is, if I understand you correctly.